# terraria xbox 360 nurse died

Tags: terraria-console

well in Terraria my nurse died but I don't know how to get her back and someone moved into her house! And I looked up stuff but they never talk about the nurse at all, and she died in a goblin army.

Comment: Build a new house for her maybe?

Answer (score 2):

All NPCs will come back so long as their conditions are met (or more accurately another of the same type but with a different name).  Make sure there's plenty more valid available housing and they should show up relatively soon.